# Cake PHP view records in two tables in same view

Tags: cakephp, view

I have two tables. Companies and Companies_billing_address. Companies table has address fields as well. I want to show fields from both tables in one view. My code in the companies view at the moment is as follows:

index.ctp:

```
    <div class="companies index">
    <h2><?php echo __('Company Details'); ?></h2>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Company Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ABN'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo "Billing Address"; ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo "Shipping Address"; ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Phone'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Email'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Fax'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Website'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Description'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('License Number'); ?></th>
            <th class="actions"><?php echo __(''); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($companies as $company): ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['ABN']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['CompaniesBillingAddress']['company_street_address']); ?>&nbsp;
        <?php echo h($company['CompaniesBillingAddress']['company_suburb']); ?>&nbsp;
      <?php echo h($company['CompaniesBillingAddress']['company_state']); ?>&nbsp;
        <?php echo h($company['CompaniesBillingAddress']['company_postcode']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_street_address']); ?>&nbsp;
        <?php echo h($company['Company']['company_suburb']); ?>&nbsp;
        <?php echo h($company['Company']['company_state']); ?>&nbsp;
        <?php echo h($company['Company']['company_postcode']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_phone']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_email']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_fax']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_website']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_description']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['license_number']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="actions">

            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $company['Company']['id'])); ?>
            </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

companiesController:

```
class CompaniesController extends AppController {

//some code

public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Company->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid company'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Company.' . $this->Company->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('company', $this->Company->find('first', $options));
    }

//some code
}
```

companiesBillingAddressesController:

```
class CompaniesBillingAddressesController extends AppController {

//some code

public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->CompaniesBillingAddress->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid companies billing address'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('CompaniesBillingAddress.' . $this->CompaniesBillingAddress->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('companiesBillingAddress', $this->CompaniesBillingAddress->find('first', $options));
    }

//some code

}
```

companies_billing_address model:

```
class CompaniesBillingAddress extends AppModel {

//some code

var $hasOne = array('Company'=>array('className'=>'Company'));
}
```

How do I get the fields in the companies_billing_address table in to the same view as companies? Can someone please help?

Comment: What is the relationship between companies and companies_billing_address tables? one to one , one to many?

Comment: companies_billing_address belongs to companies

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the "**companies_billing_address**" table's data in view.ctp, you have to make hasOne relation between "**companies_billing_address**" and "**companies**".
Then you can find "**companies_billing_address**" data in '**company**' variable.

Below is a sample for hasOne relation :-

In Company.php model :-

```
var $hasOne = array('CompaniesBillingAddress'=>array('className'=>'CompaniesBillingAddress'));
```

Comment: i changed the relationship in the "companies_billing_address" model to var $hasOne = array('Company'=>array('className'=>'Company'));
and i updated the ctp file with the fields from the companies_billing_address table. I have updated the code above.An error comes up saying undefined index: companies billing address. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in which ctp file you want to print **companies_billing_address** table's data and in which format. Is it Companies/view.ctp or CompaniesBillingAddresses/view.ctp? Also post the error message

Comment: i want the companies_billin_address table data to be displayed in the companies index.ctp
I have added my companies/index.ctp code and the companies_billing_address model above in the question.

Comment: I have updated the answer now please check and if found it works please mark it as answer